# git password problem

Tags: git

I want to set my password on push only not for pull.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: git doesn't do passwords. What transport(s) are you using?

Comment: Setting up a transport and securing it is more of a ServerFault issue.  I did it in various ways (gitosis, Apache+DAV, git-daemon), and it's not like programming at all.  Voting to close with this reason.

Comment: @Pavel: This may well be a question about the client side, i.e. pushing and pulling with different protocols, since pulling is a read-only operation and often doesn't require authentication.

Comment: as git use and a programmer, i really really want to know the answer of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two different ways of interacting with the remote repository, one of which requires a password (for pushing) and one of which doesn't (for pulling) you can do this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    # the lightweight git protocol doesn't use passwords
    # this will be used for fetch/pull
    url = "git://git.foobar.org/foobar"

    # this line is there by default; don't mess with it
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    # SO, that's not a C comment... */

    # ssh requires password/key
    # this will be used for pushes
    pushurl = ssh://user@foobar.org/foobar
```

Substitute the correct URLs in there, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Which file i have to modified to set up this. I am using git GUI for push data and git bash for pull data. I am working on windows.

Comment: This goes in the gitconfig for this particular repo. You could do it by cd-ing to the repo, and running `git config remote.origin.pushurl 'ssh://user@foobar.org/foobar'`.